# jQuery .select() inside .live() does not work on IE7 and IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-events

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('input[type="text"]').live('focus', function() {
        if (this.value == 'someValue') {
            this.select();
        }
    });
});
```

The same result with `.delegate()` and `.on()`.

What am I missing?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine for me using `.on`. Perhaps you want it to select the text when you click?

```
$("form").on("click", ":text", function(){
    if ( $(this).val() === "someValue" ) {
        $(this).select();
    }
});​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/nfKm7/

Comment: The same result, works on Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari but not on IE7 or IE8.

Comment: Working fine for me in IE7 and IE8. Be sure to press tab to focus on the element rather than clicking it: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/nfKm7/show/

Comment: @user557108 Check your console for any errors or helpful messages.

Comment: What do you mean it works with tab but not with focus? Tabbing to the input raises the focus event on the element. Tab invokes focus. Do you want it to select the text when you click on it?

Answer (score 2):

It kind of does work, the text just becomes deselected as soon as it has been selected when using the `focus` event

Using `on()` and an event other than `focus` seems to work better

[see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t2Pvz/2/)

Answer (score 0):

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/hjgZ3/

remove `$` from `function($)`

```
<input type="text" value="someValue" />  

       $(function(){
          $('input[type="text"]').live('focus', function() {
                if (this.value == 'someValue') {
                   alert('hi');                
                   //this.select();
                }
            });
        })
```